# How to save progress after first epoch in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a model which with eager execution enabled takes 10 sec/epoch to train, and with graph execution takes 1 sec/epoch. However with graph execution it spends 90 seconds on the first epoch - presumably creating/optimizing the graph.

Is there a way to save/load this step so that I can quickly retrain the model on new data without waiting 90 seconds each time for the graph creation?

I tried saving/loading the model but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's way too much custom layers/functions to post on here. I was hoping this had a general solution that wasn't specific to my case

Comment: Hi! You can use tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint to save your model in between training . Attaching reference below. Thanks!              
https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/               https://towardsdatascience.com/checkpointing-deep-learning-models-in-keras-a652570b8de6                                                                
https://towardsdatascience.com/keras-callbacks-and-how-to-save-your-model-from-overtraining-244fc1de8608